# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment nothing works inc global assignment

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am creating the yahtzee game on tkinter. I thought it would be a good learning start. I have an error saying:
***UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Dice1Butt_clicks' referenced before assignment***
I have tried setting the variables to global at the beginning of the code, I tried creating a method to set all variables to global and call it whenever I'd use the variables but nothing worked.

Not sure what else I can do?
I could potentially work without "+=" but I now more than ever want to understand what is happening and why is Python complicating everything? I am using python 2.7.13 by the way.
Can you help??

```
from tkinter import *               #Import everything from Tkinter
from random import randint          #import random integer number generator
import tkinter.messagebox           #Import messagebox method

###########  Create main window, call it root  ###########
root = Tk()

###Variables Def
global ran_no, submitv, compv, Die_clicks
##ran_no, submitv, compv, Die_clicks = IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()
ran_no = 0                                      #random value from randint method
submitv = 0                                     #value that is going to be submited to the TOTAL
compv = 0                                       #value that is going to be search for in the die (or values in case of sequences, full house, etc
Die_clicks = 0                                  #value of number of clicks on DiceallButt so that you can only roll the die three times
global Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no
##Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no = IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()
Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
global Dice1Butt_clicks, Dice2Butt_clicks, Dice3Butt_clicks, Dice4Butt_clicks, Dice5Butt_clicks
##Dice1Butt_clicks, Dice2Butt_clicks, Dice3Butt_clicks, Dice4Butt_clicks, Dice5Butt_clicks = IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()
Dice1Butt_clicks, Dice2Butt_clicks, Dice3Butt_clicks, Dice4Butt_clicks, Dice5Butt_clicks = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
global Dice1Butt_clicks
##Dice1Butt_clicks = IntVar()
Dice1Butt_clicks = 0
global TOTAL, threeOAK, fourOAK, fullhouse, smallstr8, largestr8, chance, YAHTZEE
##TOTAL, threeOAK, fourOAK, fullhouse, smallstr8, largestr8, chance, YAHTZEE = IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()
TOTAL, threeOAK, fourOAK, fullhouse, smallstr8, largestr8, chance, YAHTZEE = 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0
global Lock1, Lock2, Lock3, Lock4, Lock5
##Lock1, Lock2, Lock3, Lock4, Lock5 = BooleanVar(), BooleanVar(), BooleanVar(), BooleanVar(), BooleanVar()
Lock1, Lock2, Lock3, Lock4, Lock5 = FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE

### Methods
def globaliseVars():
    global ran_no, submitv, compv, Die_clicks, Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no, Dice1Butt_clicks, Dice1Butt_clicks, Dice2Butt_clicks, Dice3Butt_clicks, Dice4Butt_clicks, Dice5Butt_clicks, \
           TOTAL, threeOAK, fourOAK, fullhouse, smallstr8, largestr8, chance, YAHTZEE, Lock1, Lock2, Lock3, Lock4, Lock5
def resetdie():
    if Die_clicks <= 2:
        Dice1Butt.configure(state=NORMAL)
        Dice2Butt.configure(state=NORMAL)
        Dice3Butt.configure(state=NORMAL)
        Dice4Butt.configure(state=NORMAL)
        Dice5Butt.configure(state=NORMAL)
        Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Dice1Butt_clicks, Dice2Butt_clicks, Dice3Butt_clicks, Dice4Butt_clicks, Dice5Butt_clicks = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        ran_no, submitv, compv, Die_clicks = 0, 0, 0, 0
        Dice1Butt['text'] = 'Dice 1'
        Dice2Butt['text'] = 'Dice 2'
        Dice3Butt['text'] = 'Dice 3'
        Dice4Butt['text'] = 'Dice 4'
        Dice5Butt['text'] = 'Dice 5'
def lock_Dice1Butt():
    if  Lock1 == TRUE:
        Dice1ran_no = ran_no
        Dice1Butt.configure(state = DISABLED)
    else:
        Dice1Butt.configure(state = NORMAL)
def lock_Dice2Butt():
    if  Lock2 == TRUE:
        Dice2ran_no = ran_no
        Dice2Butt.configure(state = DISABLED)
    else:
        Dice2Butt.configure(state = NORMAL)
def lock_Dice3Butt():
    if  Lock3 == TRUE:
        Dice3ran_no = ran_no
        Dice3Butt.configure(state = DISABLED)
    else:
        Dice3Butt.configure(state = NORMAL)
def lock_Dice4Butt():
    if  Lock4 == TRUE:
        Dice4ran_no = ran_no
        Dice4Butt.configure(state = DISABLED)
    else:
        Dice4Butt.configure(state = NORMAL)
def lock_Dice5Butt():
    if  Lock5 == TRUE:
        Dice5ran_no = ran_no
        Dice5Butt.configure(state = DISABLED)
    else:
        Dice5Butt.configure(state = NORMAL)
def updt_TOTAL():
    TOTAL = TOTAL + submitv
def updt_Dice1Butt():
    Dice1Butt_clicks += 1
    if Dice1Butt_clicks > 2:
        Dice1Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
    Dice1ran_no = randint(1,6)
    Dice1Butt['text'] = str('You drew: ') + str(Dice1ran_no)
def updt_Dice2Butt():
    Dice2Butt_clicks += 1
    if Dice2Butt_clicks > 2:
        Dice2Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
    Dice2ran_no = randint(1,6)
    Dice2Butt['text'] = str('You drew: ') + str(Dice2ran_no)
def updt_Dice3Butt():
    Dice3Butt_clicks += 1
    if Dice3Butt_clicks > 2:
        Dice3Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
    Dice3ran_no = randint(1,6)
    Dice3Butt['text'] = str('You drew: ') + str(Dice3ran_no)
def updt_Dice4Butt():
    Dice4Butt_clicks += 1
    if Dice4Butt_clicks > 2:
        Dice4Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
    Dice4ran_no = randint(1,6)
    Dice4Butt['text'] = str('You drew: ') + str(Dice4ran_no)
def updt_Dice5Butt():
    Dice5Butt_clicks += 1
    if Dice5Butt_clicks > 2:
        Dice5Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
    Dice5ran_no = randint(1,6)
    Dice5Butt['text'] = str('You drew: ') + str(Dice5ran_no)

def updt_Die():
    Die_clicks += 1
    if Die_clicks <= 2:
        updt_Dice1Butt
        updt_Dice2Butt
        updt_Dice3Butt
        updt_Dice4Butt
        updt_Dice5Butt
    else:
        Dice1Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
        Dice2Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
        Dice3Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
        Dice4Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
        Dice5Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
        DiceallButt.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_ones():
    compv = 1
    if Dice1ran_no == compv:
        submitv =+ Dice1ran_no
    if Dice2ran_no == compv:
        submitv =+ Dice2ran_no
    if Dice3ran_no == compv:
        submitv =+ Dice3ran_no
    if Dice4ran_no == compv:
        submitv =+ Dice4ran_no
    if Dice5ran_no == compv:
        submitv =+ Dice5ran_no
    print submitv
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()    
    ones.configure(state=DISABLED)
    ONEStext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_twos():
    compv = 2
    if Dice1ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice1ran_no
    if Dice2ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice2ran_no
    if Dice3ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice3ran_no
    if Dice4ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice4ran_no
    if Dice5ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    twos.configure(state=DISABLED)
    TWOStext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_threes():
    compv = 3
    if Dice1ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice1ran_no
    if Dice2ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice2ran_no
    if Dice3ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice3ran_no
    if Dice4ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice4ran_no
    if Dice5ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    threes.configure(state=DISABLED)
    THREEStext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_fours():
    compv = 4
    if Dice1ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice1ran_no
    if Dice2ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice2ran_no
    if Dice3ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice3ran_no
    if Dice4ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice4ran_no
    if Dice5ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    fours.configure(state=DISABLED)
    FOURStext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_fives():
    compv = 5
    if Dice1ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice1ran_no
    if Dice2ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice2ran_no
    if Dice3ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice3ran_no
    if Dice4ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice4ran_no
    if Dice5ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    fives.configure(state=DISABLED)
    FIVEStext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_sixes():
    compv = 6
    if Dice1ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice1ran_no
    if Dice2ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice2ran_no
    if Dice3ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice3ran_no
    if Dice4ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice4ran_no
    if Dice5ran_no == compv:
        submitv += Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    sixes.configure(state=DISABLED)
    SIXEStext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_Sum():
    submitv += Dice1ran_no + Dice2ran_no + Dice3ran_no + Dice4ran_no + Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    sum_.configure(state=DISABLED)
    SUMtext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_threeOAK():
    threeOAK = [Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no]
    threeOAK.sort()
    if threeOAK[0]==threeOAK[1]==threeOAK[2]:
        submitv += threeOAK[0] + threeOAK[1] + threeOAK[2]
    elif threeOAK[1] == threeOAK[2] == threeOAK[3]:
        submitv += threeOAK[1] + threeOAK[2] + threeOAK[3]
    elif threeOAK[2]==threeOAK[3]==threeOAK[4]:
        submitv += threeOAK[2] + threeOAK[3] + threeOAK[4]
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice2ran_no and Dice2ran_no == Dice3ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no
##    if Dice2ran_no == Dice3ran_no and Dice3ran_no == Dice4ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no
##    if Dice3ran_no == Dice4ran_no and Dice4ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice2ran_no and Dice1ran_no == Dice4ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice2ran_no and Dice2ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
##    if Dice2ran_no == Dice3ran_no and Dice3ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
##    if Dice3ran_no == Dice4ran_no and Dice4ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice3ran_no and Dice3ran_no == Dice4ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice3ran_no and Dice3ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice4ran_no and Dice4ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
##    if Dice2ran_no == Dice4ran_no and Dice4ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    threeOAK.configure(state=DISABLED)
    THREEOAKtext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_fourOAK():
    fourOAK = [Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no]
    fourOAK.sort()
    if fourOAK[0] == fourOAK[1] == fourOAK[2] == fourOAK[3]:
        submitv += fourOAK[0] + fourOAK[1] + fourOAK[2] + fourOAK[3]
    elif fourOAK[1] == fourOAK[2] == fourOAK[3] == fourOAK[4]:
        submitv += fourOAK[1] + fourOAK[2] + fourOAK[3] + fourOAK[4]
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice2ran_no and Dice2ran_no == Dice3ran_no and Dice3ran_no == Dice4ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice3ran_no and Dice3ran_no == Dice4ran_no and Dice4ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice2ran_no and Dice2ran_no == Dice4ran_no and Dice4ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
##    if Dice1ran_no == Dice2ran_no and Dice2ran_no == Dice3ran_no and Dice3ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice1ran_no =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
##    if Dice2ran_no == Dice3ran_no and Dice3ran_no == Dice4ran_no and Dice4ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
##        submitv = submitv =+ Dice2ran_no =+ Dice3ran_no =+ Dice4ran_no =+ Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    fourOAK.configure(state=DISABLED)
    FOUROAKtext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_fullhouse():
    fullhouse = [Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no]
    fullhouse.sort()
    if fullhouse[0] == fullhouse [1] and fullhouse[2] == fullhouse [3] == fullhouse[4] or fullhouse[0] == fullhouse [1] == fullhouse[2] and fullhouse [3] == fullhouse[4] :
        submitv += fullhouse[0] + fullhouse[1] + fullhouse[2] + fullhouse[3] + fullhouse[4]
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    fullhouse.configure(state=DISABLED)
    FULLHOUSEtext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_smallstr8():
    smallstr8 = [Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no]
    smallstr8.sort()
    if smallstr8[0] == smallstr8 [1] + 1 == smallstr8[2] + 2 == smallstr8 [3] + 3:
        submitv += smallstr8[0] + smallstr8[1] + smallstr8[2] + smallstr8[3]
    elif smallstr8[1] == smallstr8 [2] + 1 == smallstr8[3] + 2 == smallstr8 [4] + 3:
        submitv += smallstr8[1] + smallstr8[2] + smallstr8[3] + smallstr8[4]
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    smallstr8.configure(state=DISABLED)
    SMALLSTR8text.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_largestr8():
    largestr8 = [Dice1ran_no, Dice2ran_no, Dice3ran_no, Dice4ran_no, Dice5ran_no]
    largestr8.sort()
    if largestr8[0] == largestr8 [1] + 1 == largestr8[2] + 2 == largestr8 [3] + 3 == largestr8[4] + 4:
        submitv += largestr8[0] + largestr8[1] + largestr8[2] + largestr8[3] + largestr8[4]
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    largestr8.configure(state=DISABLED)
    LARGESTR8text.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_chance():
    submitv += Dice1ran_no + Dice2ran_no + Dice3ran_no + Dice4ran_no + Dice5ran_no
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    chance.configure(state=DISABLED)
    CHANCEtext.configure(state=DISABLED)
def updt_YAHTZEE():
    if Dice1ran_no == Dice2ran_no == Dice3ran_no == Dice4ran_no == Dice5ran_no:
        submitv += 50
    updt_TOTAL()
    resetdie()
    YAHTZEE.configure(state=DISABLED)
    YAHTZEEtext.configure(state=DISABLED)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("You've scored a YAHTZEE!! 50 points have been added to your total. Your score is now " + str(TOTAL))



###
Dice1Butt = Button(root, text = 'Dice 1', command = updt_Dice1Butt)
Dice2Butt = Button(root, text = 'Dice 2', command = updt_Dice2Butt)
Dice3Butt = Button(root, text = 'Dice 3', command = updt_Dice3Butt)
Dice4Butt = Button(root, text = 'Dice 4', command = updt_Dice4Butt)
Dice5Butt = Button(root, text = 'Dice 5', command = updt_Dice5Butt)
Radio1Butt = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Lock Dice 1', variable = 'Lock1', value = FALSE, command = lock_Dice1Butt)
Radio2Butt = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Lock Dice 2', variable = 'Lock2', value = FALSE, command = lock_Dice2Butt)
Radio3Butt = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Lock Dice 3', variable = 'Lock3', value = FALSE, command = lock_Dice3Butt)
Radio4Butt = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Lock Dice 4', variable = 'Lock4', value = FALSE, command = lock_Dice4Butt)
Radio5Butt = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Lock Dice 5', variable = 'Lock5', value = FALSE, command = lock_Dice5Butt)
DiceallButt = Button(root, text = 'Roll All Die', command = updt_Die)
onesButt = Button(root, text = 'Ones', command = updt_ones)
twosButt = Button(root, text = 'Twos', command = updt_twos)
threesButt = Button(root, text = 'Threes', command = updt_threes)
foursButt = Button(root, text = 'Fours', command = updt_fours)
fivesButt = Button(root, text = 'Fives', command = updt_fives)
sixesButt = Button(root, text = 'Sixes', command = updt_sixes)
sumButt = Button(root, text = 'Sum', command = updt_Sum)
threeOAKButt = Button(root, text = 'ThreeOAK', command = updt_threeOAK)
fourOAKButt = Button(root, text = 'FourOAK', command = updt_fourOAK)
fullhouseButt = Button(root, text = 'FullHouse', command = updt_fullhouse)
smallstr8Butt = Button(root, text = 'Small Straight', command = updt_smallstr8)
largestr8Butt = Button(root, text = 'Large Straight', command = updt_largestr8)
chanceButt = Button(root, text = 'Chance', command = updt_chance)
YAHTZEEButt = Button(root, text = 'YAHTZEE', command = updt_YAHTZEE)

ONEStext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
TWOStext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
THREEStext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
FOURStext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
FIVEStext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
SIXEStext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
SUMtext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
THREEOAKtext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
FOUROAKtext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
FULLHOUSEtext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
SMALLSTR8text = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
LARGESTR8text = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
CHANCEtext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
YAHTZEEtext = Text(width=4, height=2, wrap =WORD)
TOTALtext = Text(width=15, height=5, wrap =WORD)

Dice1Butt.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
Dice2Butt.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
Dice3Butt.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)
Dice4Butt.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10)
Dice5Butt.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10)
Radio1Butt.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10)
Radio2Butt.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10)
Radio3Butt.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)
Radio4Butt.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)
Radio5Butt.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10)
DiceallButt.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)
onesButt.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=10)
ONEStext.grid(row=0, column=4, pady=10)
twosButt.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10)
TWOStext.grid(row=1, column=4, pady=10)
threesButt.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=10)
THREEStext.grid(row=2, column=4, pady=10)
foursButt.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=10)
FOURStext.grid(row=3, column=4, pady=10)
fivesButt.grid(row=4, column=3, pady=10)
FIVEStext.grid(row=4, column=4, pady=10)
sixesButt.grid(row=5, column=3, pady=10)
SIXEStext.grid(row=5, column=4, pady=10)
sumButt.grid(row=6, column=3, pady=10)
SUMtext.grid(row=6, column=4, pady=10)
threeOAKButt.grid(row=7, column=3, pady=10)
THREEOAKtext.grid(row=7, column=4, pady=10)
fourOAKButt.grid(row=8, column=3, pady=10)
FOUROAKtext.grid(row=8, column=4, pady=10)
fullhouseButt.grid(row=9, column=3, pady=10)
FULLHOUSEtext.grid(row=9, column=4, pady=10)
smallstr8Butt.grid(row=10, column=3, pady=10)
SMALLSTR8text.grid(row=10, column=4, pady=10)
largestr8Butt.grid(row=11, column=3, pady=10)
LARGESTR8text.grid(row=11, column=4, pady=10)
chanceButt.grid(row=12, column=3, pady=10)
CHANCEtext.grid(row=12, column=4, pady=10)
YAHTZEEButt.grid(row=13, column=3, pady=10)
YAHTZEEtext.grid(row=13, column=4, pady=10)
TOTALtext.grid(row=6, column=0, rowspan=6,sticky=W, padx=10)

###
root.title("YAHTZEE against Yuri")
root.geometry("500x800")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Stackoverflow isn't a free debugging service. Please narrow the problem down and create a [mcve].

Comment: The biggest issue I see here is your miss use of `global`. You do not need to use `global` while in the global name space. Anything written in the global is already defined in the global. Your function `def globaliseVars():` actually does nothing for you. When you use `global` within a function only code inside that function will know what is in the global you have defined. So any time you need to edit something in the global namespace from inside a function that is the time you want to use global and only for what you are using within that function.

Comment: Apologies Bryan, I just meant to give context to the problem so that you would understand what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Mike, thanks a lot for your explanation. Not sure if I understand it all, I think I am still a bit confused about what global variables in this context mean. You're right, globaliseVars(): didn't work. I used the advise from Stevo below, i.e. globalise the variables that I am using in that funcition and I was able to make it work. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In python you can access global variables by their name, but if you want to change them (using +=, -=, =, ...) you need to use *global* keyword in *that function*.

So in your case it should be:

```
def updt_Dice1Butt():
    global Dice1Butt_clicks          # note this line
    Dice1Butt_clicks += 1
    if Dice1Butt_clicks > 2:
        Dice1Butt.configure(state=DISABLED)
    Dice1ran_no = randint(1,6)
    Dice1Butt['text'] = str('You drew: ') + str(Dice1ran_no)
```

and so on ...